# String to Time in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to merge 3 datasets together and one of the columns is showing a STRING type when the other 2 are showing a TIME Type. I want to convert this STRING type into a TIME type so I can merge the dataset.

I have tried CAST, ALTER TABLE AND ALTER COLUMN. All of which didnt work gives me the error invalid time string "0:00"

The Column name is RideLength, I originally did it in excel but the dataset is to big to fit into one sheet, so I am trying it in SQL.

Comment: Take a look in the `PARSE_TIME` function: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#parse_time

Comment: what does the data looks like ?

Comment: I took the end timestamp minus the starting timestamp and subtracted to get the difference, in excel. I then copied the equation all the way down the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

if the string has timezone information, cast it to `timestamp`

```sql
  select timestamp("2023-10-04T17:17:08.025+00:00")
```

if not, you can cast it to datetime or timestamp.

```sql
select datetime("2023-10-04T17:17:08.025")
select datetime("2023-10-04T17:17:08.025")
```

Comment: I took the end timestamp minus the starting timestamp and subtracted to get the difference, in excel. I then copied the equation all the way down the dataset.